# event.preventDefault() is not working in angular.js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one issue.My requirement is when user will click on anchor tag first confirmation message will display and if user will click cancel button the page will remain as it is ,if click on OK button it will navigate to another page.Please check my code below.

```
<li ui-sref-active="active" ><a ui-sref=".profile" class="pop">Profile</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".dept" class="pop" >Department</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".usermanagement" class="pop">User Management</a></li>


$('.pop').click( function(e) {
    if (! confirm('You are about to leave - are you sure')) {
       e.preventDefault();
       //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
  });
```

> route.js:

```
var Admin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara',['ui.router', '720kb.datepicker','ngMessages','ngCapsLock','ui.bootstrap']);
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
     .state('/', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
        .state('dashboard.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/profile.html',
        controller: 'profileController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.dept', {
        url: '/dept',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dept.html',
        controller: 'deptController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.princpal', {
        url: '/princpal',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/princpal.html',
        controller: 'princpalController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.dept_head', {
        url: '/dept_head',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/depthead.html',
        controller: 'deptheadController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.usermanagement', {
        url: '/user',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/usermangement.html',
        controller: 'managementController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.role', {
        url: '/role',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/role.html',
        controller: 'roleController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.editprofile', {
        url: '/editprofile',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/editprofile.html',
        controller: 'adminProfileController'
    })
})
```

By using the above code the confirmation box is coming but when user is pressing cancel button it is also navigating to another page which should not happen.Please help me.

Comment: Move `e.preventDefault();` outside of the `if`

Comment: @Tushar : I moved this to before if statement but issue is same while i am clicking on cancel/ok  button the page is navigating.

Comment: @Tushar :No still there is same issue.In this case for cancel the if statement will execute and for ok the else part will execute.

Comment: u should not mix angularjs elements with jquery events. why not define ng-click function in an angularjs controller

Comment: @levi : Can this solved in this way ?Can you please edit your answer ?

Comment: may I ask why work with jq events while using angular? why not do things the angular way with ng-click?

Comment: @satya the problem is that you are trying to control two separate events together, ui-sref and the click... the quickest solution is not to use ui-sref in this instant but in the click use $state.go(), then you will be able to only call in on true... or you can create a click directive for this case with priority 1 which means it will be called before other events

Comment: @Jony-Y : its throwing error while using ng-click and ui-sref together.

Comment: @Jony-Y :Can you please create a solution for this ?

Comment: @satya Just use `ng-click` then remove the `ui-sref` and put the condition same with the `$state.go()` inside the `ng-click method`.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. : I can do this but there will be some problem 1st it will miss the `active` class and 2nd `cursor:pointer property on the menu`.

Comment: @satya Well, you could always make conditions to achieve `active` class. You can use `ng-class` and for the `cursor` property, you can just add `href=""` to the `anchor` to achieve `pointer` cursor.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. : Can you please edit your idea here ?

Comment: @satya First, I will need to see your `routing` codes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93753/discussion-between-satya-and-alberto-i-n-j).

Comment: @satya dude, just create a simple plunkr and we will show you...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what is happening is that the UiSref directive has registered a click event before you register yours, and it's first come first serve. This happens inside the directive's [link function](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/4da7e5913d504e975a91fbb3d7efd57cbe472077/src/stateDirectives.js#L144).

The click event runs the handler inside the directive first, sets the ui-router state, then probably waits for the digest cycle for the page to change.

During this $timeout it runs into your click event.

Your stop propagation works but it doesn't help because we already set the new state and it will take effect on the next digest cycle, even though you paused js execution with your confirm alert.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the angular.js file.
Then, you can try the following sample. For more info: ['Safe' $apply in Angular.JS](https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js)

```
$scope.safeApply = function (fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if (phase === '$apply' || phase === '$digest') {
        if (fn && (typeof (fn) === 'function')) {
            fn();
        }
    } else {
        this.$apply(fn);
    }};

$scope.safeApply(function () {
$('.pop').click( function(e) {
    if (! confirm('You are about to leave - are you sure')) {
       e.preventDefault();
       //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
  });
});
```